# How to **not** change the title bar in command prompt when running bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When I use the standard command prompt in Windows and run a bat file (or a bat file that runs a second one) the title bar in the console window changes to the name of the script being run. While I can set the title to anything I want using the `TITLE` command, that's overriden when running a bat file.

Without modifing the called bat file, how can I preserve the previous title and avoid the change?

**Edit**

As for why would I want this, let's suppose I have a bat file which sets the console title (for ease of identification) and in turn calls another bat file. During that second bat file execution, the title is lost.

```vb
@ECHO OFF
TITLE My bat file is running
REM Some commands run here, custom title is OK

REM Here title is lost and replaced by "AnotherFile"
CALL AnotherFile.bat
REM When the call returns, my custom title returns here

REM More commands with my title again
```

Question is, how can I **preserve** the title during the `CALL`?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such option unless you're using some window manipulation tool; but even then, I think you cannot enforce a certain title, but you can only undo a change...

Comment: I've found that if you set the title to nothing (`title  `) then the filename doesn't show up, but that's probably not what you're looking for. May I ask why you need this? There might be a workaround if I knew exactly what you were doing.

Comment: @SomethingDark Thanks, but it doesn't works neither. An empty title works, but as soon as I call a bat file, it still shows the bat file name, as with any other title set. I'll update the question to reflect more on this.

Comment: I have the same requirement - i run simple exe from within a command prompt but want to set/hardcode title so as it retains a value I configure rather than the value of the exe